# How to set focus on browser Firefox window controlled by Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, x11, selenium-firefoxdriver

My OS is Ubuntu. I'd want to set OS window focus to Firefox window controlled by Webdriver. I'd want to do it as I want to press Ctrl+S using XDoTool and then do some OS native mouse clicks/keyboard keys presses to handle Save As OS window.

I tried:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content
driver.execute_script('window.focus();')
```

But it doesn't change focus.

Also I thought about using xdotool and selecting window by name but I may have other windows with the same name opened.

How can I set window focus to that browser window?

Comment: When you open a browser from Web driver, defaultly the opened browser had focus until the web driver instance destroyed. The window will lose focus when you use `switchTo.window()` command. Please make us clear how you say you will lost focus from Firefox window?

Comment: @Manigandan I manually set window focus to another application. I don't want Webdriver to have focus always. Also I run Webdriver instances in parallel so I can't focus on all of them

Comment: Andrey : I am not much aware on Ubuntu OS. But in Web driver after you launch the browser whatever can be done manually in the other application nothing will affect the focus on opened browser session. So it's not possible to change the browser window focus manually. In the 1st line of the posted code you used `default-content` it is used to switch over to the top or first frame. May i know whats the need there?

Comment: @Manigandan It's just what I've tried.

Comment: @Manigandan I want browser to have OS window focus, not internal browser focus. Read second sentence of the question

Comment: So, let me get this straight. You don't want the browser window to have system focus, except sometimes you do, like when the system OS dialogs for saving a file are displayed, right? You can't have it both ways. Either you want the browser being automated to not have focus so you can continue to use the machine for other tasks, or you're willing to dedicate your machine to the task of browser automation. Sorry, they're mutually exclusive. Also, requiring window focus makes the multiple instance case very difficult. You'd have to modify the WebDriver source to make that happen.

Comment: @JimEvans Thanks for response. Currently I wrote code that switches focus to browser window at OS level (I used XdoTool for it) when I need it. I did it without modifying browser source code.

Comment: @AndreyBotalov I was unclear. I should've said, "You'd have to modify the WebDriver source to allow WebDriver to automatically handle the focus-switching for you." You can, of course, write your own code outside your WebDriver code that will handle OS-native windowing, but you need to be careful how you determine which window you're actually interested in, since WebDriver provides no native way to get an OS-level identifier for the browser window(s) it's controlling.